# EEL Парсинг вывод переменной python в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, парсер, beautiful-soup, eel

Привет пытаюсь запарсить сайт и получить span с beautifulsoup4 вот код index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Eel App</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<center>
<div class="box">
    <h1>1 BTC = <span id="changeme"></span></h1>
</div>
</center>

<script src="eel.js"></script>
<script>

async function callme(){

    const value = (await eel.call_me('place?')());

    document.querySelector('#changeme').innerHTML = value;
    console.log(value);
}

callme();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Вот код main.py:

```
import eel
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

eel.init('web')

@eel.expose

def call_me(place):
    url = 'https://ru.investing.com/crypto/bitcoin/btc-usd'
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml') 
    quotes = soup.find("span", id="last_last")
    print(quotes)
    return quotes

eel.start("index.html", size = (500, 500))
```

Всё ок сайт парситься я получаю данные и они выводяться в windows powershell (консоли), **НО ОНИ НЕ ВЫВОДЯТЬСЯ В INDEX.HTML ТАМ Я ПОЛУЧАЮ NULL**
**ПОЖАЛУЙСТА ПОМОГИТЕ!**

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте

```
import json
quotes = quotes.json()
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]